# "'portaudio.h' file not found" error in XCode 5.1

Tags: c, xcode, macos, portaudio

I've downloaded the [portaudio](http://www.portaudio.com/download.html) codebase and compiled it fully with source, and installed it to my system with these commands:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

But XCode is complaining to me, even when I put `-lportaudio` in the **Other Linker Flags** for the project settings.

[image]

I've researched this problem and tried whatever I could find on Stack Overflow, but there was no decisive answer that would work for me.  Any advice on how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm using an older version of XCode and haven't bothered looking at how the interface might have changed in the newer versions, but this is generally solved for me by modifying the User Search Paths under your project settings. Look at the screenshot, add `/usr/local/include` to Header Search Paths and make Always Search User Paths "Yes." That should do the trick

[image]

---

**Edit**:

One more thing to note, this is only `/usr/local/include` because that's the default install directory for the portaudio.h file in the portaudio build (as it is with many libraries).

If you have a different prefix other than `/usr/local/include`, add that instead.

Comment: Just looked at the title of the question again. I'm actually using XCode 4.5.2, this should work for you.